# Dynamically adding/removing items to array properties in ASP.NET MVC 4 views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

Here is my simplified model containing a 1 to many relationship

```
public class RealEstate
{
    public int ValueUSD { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class RealEstateAgent
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public RealEstate[] HandledRealEstates { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my controller class:

```
public class AgentController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(RealEstateAgent agent)
    {
        try
        {
            int realestateCount = agent.HandledRealEstates.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("Agent {0} handles {1} real estates.", agent.FirstName, realestateCount);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The business requirement is to have views that allows the user to create/edit the agents TOGETHER with their real estates on a single page using add/remove buttons for real estates.

I am rather new in ASP.NET MVC, just learning the concepts. **Could anyone show me an example, how my Create view should look like, in order to get model binding the MVC-ish way?**

Comment: you should read this post http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way of creating views is by having them generate using scaffolding.

here is a site that explains all you need to know.
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/mvcscaffolding-standard-usage/